# Problems with Word Search program

Tags: java

I am trying to create a word search program that puts words from a file into a matrix character by character.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchWord {
    public SearchWord() {

    }

    public void getMatrix() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Cameron/Desktop/words.txt");
        ArrayList<Character> words;

        String largest = " ";
        int col = 0;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner newsc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String first = sc.next();
            String first1 = sc.nextLine();

            if (first.length() > largest.length()) {
                largest = first;
                col = largest.length();
            }

            words = new ArrayList<Character>();

            for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
                words.add(first.charAt(i));
            }

            char[] chars = new char[words.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                chars[i] = words.get(i);
            }

            char data[][] = new char[largest.length()][col];

            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < largest.length(); j++) {
                    data[i][j] = chars[i];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(data[i][j] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        SearchWord check = new SearchWord();
        check.getMatrix();
    }
}
```

I have the words ladybug, fence, and hamburger in my words.txt file but I am having trouble reading them into the matrix correctly. I eventually want to have the words overlap on common letters. I also want the blank spaces to be filled with a random letter but I can get to that later.

It should look something like this:

```
alaaaaafa
hamburger
adaaaaana 
ayaaaaaca
abaaaaaea 
auaaaaaaa
agaaaaaaa
```

But instead it does this:

```
l l l l l l l 
a a a a a a a 
d d d d d d d 
y y y y y y y 
b b b b b b b 
u u u u u u u 
g g g g g g g 
h h h h h h h h h 
a a a a a a a a a 
m m m m m m m m m 
b b b b b b b b b 
u u u u u u u u u 
r r r r r r r r r 
g g g g g g g g g 
e e e e e e e e e 
r r r r r r r r r 
f f f f f f f f f 
e e e e e e e e e 
n n n n n n n n n 
c c c c c c c c c 
e e e e e e e e e
```

Comment: `count`, `newsc` and `first1` are never used. What is their purpose?

Comment: @bcsb1001  I was experimenting before this and I left those variables there. The count was supposed to count the number of characters in a word in order to find the longest to get the size of the matrix but I ended up using `longest.length()` for that. I had a problem before where I would use two `while` loops and the scanner wouldn't start at the beginning for the second one so I just copied the scanner over to make `newsc`. With `first1` I was experimenting with `.next()` and `.nextLine()`.

Comment: Why dont you give us a brief description of what the program is trying to accomplish. The character by character matrix part of a word search doesn't make sense to me. Are you trying to allow the user to enter a word and check to see if the word matches a word found in your file? If not, give an explanation of the overall purpose of the program. Not only that, you say 'matrix' and typically I think of a 2x2 array (at least). So why would you need a matrix and what do you expect the matrix to contain and how is it supposed to be used?

Comment: I have some words in a file, each on separate lines, that I wanting to read into a matrix in order to create a word search. I was thinking that it would be easiest to read each word in character by character because they would each be placed into individual spots. The words should overlap common characters and the blank spots should be filled with a random letter.

Comment: Yea, but you are explaining your implementation. Can you just explain what the program is intending to accomplish?

Comment: That is what it is trying to accomplish. It's practice with matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two errors in the program, that account for both of your problems.

First, you allocate the array using `chars.length` rather than `largest.length`.  Unless the final string you read happens to also be the largest, you will get memory errors.

And second, you use `println` rather than `print` to display the characters; you already have a `println` in your outer loop, so it appears that you correctly planned to use print in the inner loop.

Also, I have done what you are trying, but in C++ (no, sorry, won't share *that* code), and as a helpful tip, you might want to take a look at this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm

Comment: I changed the `char data[][] = new char[col][chars.length];` with `char data[][] = new char[largest.length()][col];` and fixed the printing error at the end and got what is above in the original question.

Comment: I did some testing and the problem seems to be with the double for loop that reads the characters from the `chars` array into the `data` matrix.